# Qemu can't find an existing symbol in libpangocairop.so library

Tags: linux, ubuntu, operating-system, qemu

I just installed qemu on my Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS via apt-get, but when I executed `qemu-system-aarch64` command it said:

> qemu-system-aarch64: symbol lookup error:
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol:
> cairo_ft_scaled_font_unlock_face

After that, I used `nm -gD libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 | grep cairo_ft`  command to check symbols in the mentioned library and I found:

> U cairo_ft_scaled_font_unlock_face

which indicated the symbol was there in the library. So I wonder what caused the qemu binary couldn't find the existing symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"U" means "undefined" -- that is, libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 requires this symbol, and expects it to be provided by some other library.

On my Ubuntu system this is provided by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2.11600.0, where 'nm -gD' lists it with a 'T' meaning "defined in this file's text section". (I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 so the exact libcairo .so filename is probably different for you.)

```
00000000000c1f30 T cairo_ft_scaled_font_unlock_face
```

On Ubuntu that library should be in the 'libcairo2' package. However, the Ubuntu package that provides 'libpangocairo' depends on libcairo2 and should have installed it automatically. You should therefore check whether there's something broken on your system (e.g. you have an incompatible install of parts of libcairo or libpango in /usr/local or otherwise on your library load path before the system versions of the library, or you've accidentally managed to delete some of the files that libcairo2 installs).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the meaning of 'U', which makes the problem more clearly! But I tried 'apt-get remove --purge' to remove libpango and libpangocairo from the system and also used 'apt-get autoremove' to clean the unnecessary dependencies. After I downloaded the source code of QEMU and built it, the error was firstly about gtk-3 before I used apt-get to install gtk-3, then the error still turned to the same one as mentioned in the question description. Could you please give me some more suggestions or clues about how to investigate and fix this? Thanks!

Comment: The problem is not with the system versions of those libraries, but likely with some other busted version elsewhere on your system. Install the system libraries, and make sure that those are being used. Compiling your own QEMU is a complete red herring -- as you've found, it changed nothing.